# Z-index on header not working despite all divs having set positions

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a simple react component. There is a `div` for the header and a `div` for the rest of the page. The `div` for the header has a fixed position and the `div` for the body has a position set to relative. I set the `z-index` for the header to be higher than that of the body but it is still being overlapped and I am not sure why.

This is my JSX code:

```
    <div id="host">
      <div className="header">
      </div>
      <div className="container-top body">
        <h1>Start a Game</h1>
        <p>
          Select a Game Below or{" "}
          <Link id="create-game-link" to="/create-quiz">
            Create your Own!
          </Link>
        </p>
        {renderAction()}
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.container-top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3a5a40;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px #333333;
}

.body {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt look like a React issue per-se. Could you make a css/html jsfiddle?

Comment: why you need `z-index` for the body?

Comment: I probably don't. I just put it there to see if it would do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the background color in the header, if it is transparent other divs are visible.

Comment: No I don't. You use className when using React.

Comment: Ok. My bad. What if you set a background color for the classy .header?

Comment: Surprisingly enough, that worked, thanks! I forgot I didn't set the background color for the header.